# How to achieve this layout in react native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have 3 Views, I want two of them, let's call them View1 and View2, to be vertically aligned to center, and a third one, View3, to be horizontally aligned under View2.

I already tried with flex containers but I was only able to vertically align View1 with View2 and View3 as a whole.

I think using margin is not an option since I do not know the dimensions a priori.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do this with flex-box by itself. You'll have to use `onLayout` property on View2 and then get it's height / width and place View 1 and 3 accordingly using margin

Answer (score 0):

Did this [sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/flexbox-center-alignment) fulfill your requirements?

```js
import { View, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

// You can import supported modules from npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

// or any files within the Snack
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <View style={styles.center}>
          <View style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.center}>
          <View
            style={{ width: 150, height: 150, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <View style={styles.center}>
          {/*<View style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'green' }} />*/}
        </View>
        <View style={styles.center}>
          <View style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'brown', marginTop: 50 }} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  center: {
    flex:1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```